# Query database and return rows where two variables are satisfied?

Tags: php, html, sql, database

I'm attempting to make a basic interactive fiction game using a database and PHP.
Basically, a user will begin at room 1 and enter a command ('N', 'E', 'S', 'W'), at which point a query will be ran that is supposed to use the current room (initially 1) and the entered command to return a new room.

The first problem I've run into is that I cannot set the first initial room number to 1, without it being persistently reset every time the form is submitted.

Secondly, it doesn't appear that I can reliably return the new room based on the two variables fed into the query. Here is my PHP as follows:

```
<?php
ini_set("error_reporting",E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
ini_set("display_errors",1);

include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/flourish/toinclude.php";
$connstr="ISOMTEACHING5\INFOSYS280";
$mydb=new fDatabase("mssql", "Games","mytest","",$connstr,61495);


if ($_REQUEST["submitter"]=="Go")
{
    $command = $_POST['command'];
    $sendcommand=$mydb->query("SELECT ".
        "Exits.ToRoom ".
        "FROM Exits ".
        "WHERE Exits.Direction=%s",
        $command,
        "AND Exits.FromRoom=%s",
        $roomno
        );

    if ($sendcommand->countReturnedRows()==0)
    {
        $errormessage="alert('Cannot go ".$command." from here!');";
    }
    else
    {
        $commandheader=$sendcommand->fetchRow();
        echo "From Room ".$roomno."<br>";
        $toroom=$commandheader['ToRoom'];
        echo $toroom;
        $roomno=$toroom;
        echo "<br> new current room: ".$roomno;

    }
}
?>
```

The HTML is a basic form, where the submit button's value is "Go" and the 'command' is simply the user input of the possible commands.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am new to PHP and databases as a whole and cannot seem to sort this out. I can provide any further information if necessary.

Cheers!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please expand on the questions. You say you cannot set the initial room number to 1. Which bit of code is supposed to do that and what happens if you try it? What do you mean you cannot *reliably* return the new room? What is the problem you see?

Comment: A side note about security. Never, ever, under any circumstances accept unsanitised input from the user. In your example, the problem is `$command = $_POST['command'];`. It allows user to send something other than NWSE, which may have very bad consequences (google 'SQL injection'). Always make sure that user input is one of allowed values. I know it's probably just a fun/learning project, but it's good to start with good habits.